# Ormlite and PostgreSQL - Error inserting text array with custom persister

Tags: postgresql, ormlite

I have been working to setup Ormlite as the primary data access layer between a PostgreSQL database and Java application.  Everything has been fairly straightforward, until I started messing with PostgreSQL's array types.  In my case, I have two tables that make use of text[] array type.  Following the documentation, I created a custom data persister as below:

```
public class StringArrayPersister extends StringType {

    private static final StringArrayPersister singleTon = new StringArrayPersister();

    private StringArrayPersister() {
        super(SqlType.STRING, new Class<?>[]{String[].class});
    }

    public static StringArrayPersister getSingleton() {
        return singleTon;
    }


    @Override
    public Object javaToSqlArg(FieldType fieldType, Object javaObject) {
        String[] array = (String[]) javaObject;


        if (array == null) {
            return null;
        } else {

            String join = "";
            for (String str : array) {
                join += str +",";
            }

            return "'{" + join.substring(0,join.length() - 1) + "}'";
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Object sqlArgToJava(FieldType fieldType, Object sqlArg, int columnPos) {
        String string = (String) sqlArg;

        if (string == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return string.replaceAll("[{}]","").split(",");
        }
    }
}
```

And then in my business object implementation, I set up the persister class on the column likeso:

```
   @DatabaseField(columnName = TAGS_FIELD, persisterClass = StringArrayPersister.class)
    private String[] tags;
```

When ever I try inserting a new record with the Dao.create statement, I get an error message saying tags is of type text[], but got character varying... However, when querying existing records from the database, the business object (and text array) load just fine.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

PostGresSQL 9.2.  The exact error message:

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "tags" is
>   of type text[] but expression is of type character varying   Hint: You
>   will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

Comment: What's the exact error text? Also, what Postgres version?

Comment: I updated the original post with this info.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not used *ormlite* before (I generally use *MyBatis*), however, I believe the proximal issue is this code:

```
 private StringArrayPersister() {
        super(SqlType.STRING, new Class<?>[]{String[].class});
    }
```

`SqlType.String` is mapped to `varchar` in *SQL* in the *ormlite* code, and so therefore I believe is the proximal cause of the error you're getting. See [ormlite SQL Data Types info](http://ormlite.com/data_types.shtml) for more detail on that.

Try changing it to this:

```
private StringArrayPersister() {
        super(SqlType.OTHER, new Class<?>[]{String[].class});
    }
```

There may be other tweaks necessary as well to get it fully up and running, but that should get you passed this particular error with the `varchar` type mismatch.

Comment: In my case, I had to add column definition :

@DatabaseField(persisterClass = StringArrayPersister.class, columnDefinition = "text[]")
private String[] sections;